# Free IOS emulator for PC?

Tags: windows, ios, emulator

I'm looking for a BlueStacks alike IOS emulator for PC. I want it to play an app that it was done only for IOS, not for developing software. I found lists of 10-15 IOS emulators, but they either have several broken links or they arent free. There is also an apparently free one that when I download it and try to install it, it says damaged file, called Desktop Iphone, I dont know if it's somewhere else available for download and functional, but the files from the 2 links I found dont work.

Is there a free IOS emulator for PC that works?

Comment: Apple only allows to execute iOS on Apple hardware. So every emulator provided for download that contains an real iOS system will pretty fast get a visit from the lawyer of Apple... I assume this is the reason you only encounter dead links.

Comment: @Robert oh, that's so bad.

Comment: @robert may be an IOS emulator doesnt qualify as to be exactly IOS? Many links and even paid software which dont have copyright claims in Google search

Comment: @robert according to this link IOS emulators are legal https://frameboxxindore.com/linux/are-ios-emulators-legal.html

Comment: iOS is not an open source OS like Linux (only a few tiny parts base on open source code), there is only one source for an iOS system, otherwise you would have to reimplements the whole OS including an pretty large API.

Comment: They only write that downloading and using it is not illegal (and I am not sure if this site can be considered as trustful source) but they do not talk about providing an iOS emulator for download. In my interpretation this is the part which causes the legal problems.

Comment: The linked emulator site isn't talking about iOS emulators, it's talking about things like NES being emulated **on** iOS. Applications which emulate iOS itself can only legitimately be run on Apple hardware, the same as any Apple OS.

Comment: @tetsujin If I understand correctly, Microsoft releases a product that enables you to build IOS apps on PC. How can be illegal if a large company like Microsoft does it? "iOS apps with Visual Studio Tools for Xamarin
If you haven’t tried app development with Xamarin yet, it’s available as part of Visual Studio on PC and Mac (including the free Visual Studio Community Edition) and enables you to build apps for iPhone, iPad, Apple Watch, and Apple TV – using C# and F#"  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-and-xamarin-take-ios-support-to-11/

Comment: You can code in VS, Xaramin, Swift or Unity... but you have to use Xcode to compile. See https://mindster.com/how-develop-ios-apps-windows/